# How to import JavaScript library from CDN links in a node.js script

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a script called `myscript.js`. I execute the script usually
using this command:

```
$ node myscript.js
```

How can I include the JStat Library via the CDN address in the script:

```
//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jstat/1.2.1/jstat.min.js
```

Answer (score 14):

There isn't any logic built into node's require to do this.

If you are certain that this library supports use on the server-side (not all libraries are "isomorphic", that is, usable on both client and server side), then you can download it and require it locally (`require('./jstat.min.js')`).

The best way would be to find it on npm and install it, like any other node module.

Note: There isn't really an advantage to using a cdn on the server side. The main use case for a cdn is providing a cacheable copy to users' browsers, but users' browsers won't be running node code.

Comment: A lot of code examples on the web assume that you're running in a browser and provide script tags that load something from a CDN. However, I often want to just use that library in a simple nodejs script. That's a common use case. If the same library can be found in npm, that's great, but finding it might take too much time. And, of course, you wouldn't expect to use a library that assumes the presence of a DOM or other browser artifact.