# Including CDN library in node jas file

Tags: node.js

How can I include CDN library in a nodejs file? I have to include `<script src="https://cdn.auth0.com/js/lock/10.23.1/lock.min.js"></script>` in a nodejs file and can't do `npm install auth0-lock` instead. How can I insert this  tag in nodejs file to work properly?

Comment: Your question is similar to this post, please check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7809397/how-to-require-from-url-in-node-js

Comment: Also look at [Loading remote js file using require with node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23566310/loading-remote-js-file-using-require-with-node-js).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to require from URL in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7809397/how-to-require-from-url-in-node-js)

Comment: This has been answered in another post
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31240680/how-to-import-javascript-library-from-cdn-links-in-a-node-js-script